# How to use nx run-many with different configurations?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm looking into using the ["run many"](https://nx.dev/p/a/cli/run-many#configuration) command but I can't figure out how to specify configurations, I would like to do something like this but it doesn't work. It only detects 2 projects and not 4, is is not possible to use run-many to run the same app with different configurations ?

The goal is to launch the same app 2 times but with a different configuration, without chaining nx serve but using nx run-many so I can launch everything with one `npm run start:all`

`nx run-many --target=serve --projects=app1,app2,app1,app2 --configurations=dev-front-1,dev-back-1,dev-front-2,dev-back-2`

`nx run-many --target=serve --projects=app1:dev-front-1,app2:dev-back-1,app1:dev-front-2,app2:dev-back-2`

Comment: Not sure why this doesn’t work, however, you could also consider run-commands (sorry on mobile so can only link to a tweet for an example): https://twitter.com/dutch_guy/status/1427648161158504462?s=21

Comment: @MikeOne I didn't know about this command !!!! Thanks it's gonna be useful, and for other things as well !

Comment: Absolutely- it made my life a lot easier!